Connection between multicollinearity and problem of identification in Simultaneous Equations Model
Is there any connection between multicollinearity and problem of identification in Simultaneous Equations Model?
I know Multicollinearity is the occurrence of high intercorrelations among two or more independent variables in a multiple regression model, and,
Simultaneous equations models are a type of statistical model in which the dependent variables are functions of other dependent variables, rather than just independent variables.
Was wondering if there is any connection between the two? Is multicollinearity present in SEM?
